# How to send mail from godaddy server using gmail account

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following is given the code, need help. I have the Goddady server, but I am not able to send mail.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['SMTP_Secure'] = 'ssl';
$config['smtp_server'] = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net'; //smtp.gmail.com  
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'; //smtp.gmail.com 
$config['smtp_port'] = '465' 
$config['smtp_user'] = '....@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '******';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; 
$config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html 
$config['validation'] = true; // bool whether to validate email or not
$this->email->initialize($config); 
$this->email->from('....@gmail.com', 'sender_name');   
$this->email->to('....@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); if($this->email->send())
{
    echo "Working"; echo $this->email->print_debugger();}else{echo "Not working";
}
```

Comment: Any one know about it

Comment: see this [send-receive-godaddy-email-gmail/](https://artkenya.net/send-receive-godaddy-email-gmail/)